# Problem with Little's law

Tags: queueing-theory

I am estimating number of threads required by my server to execute clients requests efficiently and initially I starts 4 threads on the server.Request arrival rate on my server is 4 request/sec and each request takes fixed amount of time to complete with following time descriptions. The arrival rate is fixed and all new request arrivals have fixed service time.

$$
  \text{Request}_1 = 0.2 \text{ sec}\quad
  \text{Request}_2 = 0.9 \text{ sec}\quad 
  \text{Request}_3 = 0.6 \text{ sec}\quad 
  \text{Request}_4 = 0.5 \text{ sec}
$$

Request arrival rate is 4. Since each request would be assigned to each thread so no waits are there so Average Response time is $(0.2+0.9+0.6+0.5)/4= 0.55$

Applying [Little's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little's_law) to estimate required threads on server to serve requests is now as follows

$$
\begin{align}
  \text{Required threads on server } 
    &= \text{Request arrival rate } * \text{ average response time} \\
    &= 4*(0.55) \\
    &= 2.2
\end{align}
$$

That is there should be 2 threads only for request arrivals of 4 req/sec with given service times, and in this case any 2 requests must wait on each cycle of arrivals because we have only 2 resources (threads) and arrival rate is 4 requests/sec. So any 2 requests must wait and this results in increased response time. kindly help me in this regard. Am I doing calculations right? Why is Little's law is not suited for scenarios having service times less than 1 seconds?

Comment: First, notice that you find 2.2 required thread. With only two threads, it's to be expected to have increased waiting time. With three threads, while one rerquest must wait at arrival, it can be assigned before the next round of arrival.